# Sql moving values from one column to two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

My problem is as follows - in the database I have a Products table with a size column. However, I have now created two new columns x_size and y_size and I wanted to move the values from the size column to these 2 columns. For example, in the database I have a record, where the size column value is 100x200, now I want to transfer '100' to the new x_size column and '200' to the y_size column, and so for each of the records in this table.

I was trying with :

```
UPDATE `post` SET `x_size `=`size`
UPDATE `post` SET `y_size `=`size`
```

But this updates the value of the entire size column, not just part of it. I will be grateful for your help

Comment: Are all of your values in size column in this exact format? 100x200

Comment: Some are for example 100x200x10 and some in format 100x200

Comment: What does the third number represent, do you want to move that somewhere as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple records that you want to transfer from size column, you could do fetch all the records from your table, and then split your size values using [PHP explode()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-explode-function/) function. Since you tagged Laravel, here's the simple Laravel solution:

```
$products = Products::get();
foreach ($products as $product){
    $size = explode('x', $product->size);
    $product->x_size = $size[0]; //First element from exploded array
    $product->y_size = $size[1]; //Second element from exploded array
    $product->save();
 }
```

Tinker output:

```
>>> $size = '100x200';
=> "100x200"
>>> $exlpodedArray = explode('x', $size);
=> [
     "100",
     "200",
   ]
>>> $x_size = $exlpodedArray[0];
=> "100"
>>> $y_size = $exlpodedArray[1];
=> "200"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
UPDATE post
    SET x_size = substring_index(size, 'x', 1),
        y_size = substring_index(size, 'x', -1)
```